# admin site looks different in production environment

Tags: django

so I'm building a basic site to learn django, and i am currently setting up the admin site.  when launch the site through

python manage.py runserver

i can go to the website and it looks pretty just like this. http://cl.ly/2Z3A2n0I1E140X3k180h

but when i load the site through my apache web server it looks like this. http://cl.ly/3H3r1G2D193p462t3641

can anyone help me?

it looks to me like the admin site is not able to load the proper template on the live site. but i did not setup any special template. and when i look at the permissions of the template folder it seems to be fine... maybe not.  any help?

Comment: Your CSS and other media is probably being served properly by Apache.please post your Apache config and django settings.py

Comment: Yeah you probably need to configure your webserver to serve the static files (like the admin's CSS).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, sorry for the long story:

First, find out where your django installation rests:
in the CLI:

```
>>> import django
>>> django
<module 'django' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/__init__.pyc'>
```

The this is the path (except for the `__init__.pyc`, of course) to your Django installation.
Now, in your media directory, you could create a symbolic link to the directory that the admin media is located in (this way you will not have to copy the files to your media directory).

Assuming that you are in your media directory use this command to create dynamic link to the admin media directory (the first argument to `ln -s` should of course be your django path that we got retrieved earlier):

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/ admin
```

Now in your `settings.py` you can use something like this:

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/admin/
```

You will also have to add this directive to your Apache config:

```
Alias /media/ /full/path/to/your/django/site
```

Comment: do you have any tips on how to go about fixing that..? like i said, I'm new.

Comment: wow thanks for the detailed description. that all makes a lot of sense.  only question i have, that last line. the "Alias /media/ /full/path to blab la bla     where about do i put that in the apache conic file?

Comment: in the Virtualhost directive of your site.